# Нужна ли запятая перед "для которого"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Загрузите фото объекта() для которого требуется анализ и узнайте точную стоимость услуги.*

Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Необходима — и перед «и узнайте» тоже! Это — СПП (сложноподчинённое предложение), а «для которого требуется анализ» — его придаточное предложение, и поскольку оно стоит в середине фразы, то выделяется запятыми С ДВУХ СТОРОН.